# R - How to display only one hover text on a multiple lines chart with plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I use the code below to plot a multiple lines chart and having hover informations with ggplotly :

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(text = paste("Epoch : ", epoch, "\nTrain Loss : ", loss, "\nTest Loss : ", test_loss))
g <- ggplot(
        data,
        aes(x = epoch + 1, text = text, group = 1)
    ) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = loss, color = 'train set loss'),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = test_loss, color = 'test set loss'),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    labs(x = 'epoch', y = 'loss') +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('train set loss' = 'blue', 'test set loss' = 'red')) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15)
    )
g <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = 'text') %>%
    config(displayModeBar = F)
g <- layout(g, legend = list(x = 0.75, y = 0.99), hovermode = 'x unified')
g
```

The corresponding result is the image below :
[image]

The problem is that I woul like to have only one hover text at the top or the bottom and not two (because as you can see, they are the same right now). I thought that with `hovermode = 'x unified'` would do the job, but it seems that it is not.

Thanks in advance guys.

**Edit**

The code below, with adding 2 columns `text1` and `text2` instead of just `text` and adding the text parameter into the aesthtitics of the two geom_line works and does the image below :

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(text1 = paste("Epoch : ", epoch + 1, "\nLoss : ", loss)) %>%
    mutate(text2 = paste("Epoch : ", epoch + 1, "\nLoss : ", test_loss))
g <- ggplot(
        data,
        aes(x = epoch + 1)
    ) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = loss, color = 'train set loss', text = text1, group = 1),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    geom_line(
        aes(y = test_loss, color = 'test set loss', text = text2, group = 1),
        size = 0.8
    ) +
    labs(x = 'epoch', y = 'loss') +
    scale_color_manual(values = c('train set loss' = 'blue', 'test set loss' = 'red')) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12),
        axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15)
    )
g <- ggplotly(g, tooltip = 'text') %>%
    config(displayModeBar = F)
g <- layout(g, legend = list(x = 0.75, y = 0.99), hovermode = 'x unified')
g
```

[image]

However, this solution brings the following message : `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text`

Comment: default `aes` meets your need.  Try not using `tooltip = "text"` in ggplotly.

Comment: By doing this, I have loss, color and epoch + 1 as hover informations, although I would like only loss and epoch, that is why i used a text.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try `tooltip = c("x","y")`.  See example below

```
# create some data
x <- c(1:10); y <- x*x ; yy <- x+x
df1 <- data.frame(x,y,yy)

p1 <- ggplot(df1,aes(x=x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y, color = 'train set loss')) +
  geom_line(aes(y=yy, color = 'train set loss2')) 

p2 <- ggplotly(p1, tooltip = c("x","y")) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = F)
p2 <- layout(p2, legend = list(x = 0.75, y = 0.99), hovermode = 'x unified')
p2
```

[image: output]

Comment: That helped me a looooot. So the solution is to set 2 different text variables for aesthetic directly in geom_line.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Oh, I have edited the post, you should see it, there is something interesting, like it is working but I get a warning message.